# How to set textField becomeFirstResponder via selector

Tags: swift, uitextfield, selector, becomefirstresponder, inputview

I wrote a `UITextfield` extension to build my own toolbar for custom inputs:

```
func addToolbar(selector: Selector? = nil) {
    let action = selector == nil ? #selector(resignFirstResponder) : selector
    
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: action)

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneButton]
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    returnKeyType = .done
}
```

I use it like this:

```
let myPickerView = UIPickerView()
myPickerView.dataSource = myPickerViewBehavior
myPickerView.delegate = myPickerViewBehavior
    
if let selected = value {
    let selectedIndex = PickableItemType.index(of: selected.rawValue)
    myPickerView.selectRow(selectedIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
    
myTextField.delegate = self
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView
myTextField.addToolbar(selector: #selector(nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder))
```

As you can imagine I want the next `UITextField` to `becomeFirstResponder` after the user pressed done in the toolbar.
But nothing happening.
For testing I've tried using a simple `@objs func` with `print` statement and/or `nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder` inside, same result.
I've also tried to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `#selector(nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder)`, also same result.

So I guess it has something to do with the #selector mechanic why the code doesn't work.

P.S.: if `selector == nil` inside `addToolbar` , `#selector(resignFirstResponder)` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the wrong `target:` while setting up `doneButton`.

If you also supply the target in `addToolbar:` method like:

```
func addToolbar(target: Any? = nil, selector: Selector? = nil) {
    let object = target ?? self
    let action = selector ?? #selector(resignFirstResponder)
    
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: object, action: action)

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneButton]
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    returnKeyType = .done
}
```

This should work:

```
firstTextField.addToolbar(target: secondTextField, selector: #selector(becomeFirstResponder))
```

Here's a small test result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugFwK.jpg

Comment: That's it and makes absolute sense! Thank You.